# Windows forms with WebApplication

Tags: c#, winforms, web-applications, asp.net-core

Im a web developer, and made an .net core web app, but my client want to use it like a program. I discovered that windows forms can run a chromium component that renders a web page.

There is a way that i can deploy my web app project within the windows forms?

Comment: Create a distributable package with some type of installer like InstallShield and add your program's files to it.

Comment: What does your client actually mean by "like a program" is every client going to have to host a webserver?

Comment: Is the money worth the hassle? My crystal ball predicts a maintenance nightmare ...

Comment: Indeed, @Fildor mines says the same.

Comment: @user6144226 he is going to host it locally. But i guess i made it, just using a .bat file, to run `dotnet restore && start "" http://localhost:5000 && dotnet run` discarding the winforms

Comment: How many installations are we talking about? Like one single workstation or >10, >100 ?

Comment: Got it, gonna host it in a server of mine, and make a winform with this `cefsharp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using CefSharp:

> https://cefsharp.github.io/
>
> https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Tutorial
>
> https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1058700/Embedding-Chrome-in-your-Csharp-App-using-CefSharp

I hope that helps!